# Can two Key Values be same in a Map

Tags: c++, linux, boost, stl, dictionary

I have defined a Map

```
boost::unordered_map<"std::string,std::string">m_mapABC ;
```

And I Store values in it Like m_mapABC[strValue1]=strValue2;

And Assume that i store 10 entries to the map.In that case can the same  Key Value be used to store 10 different Values..or  will it be over written every time...I guess it would.
In that case using  `std::pair` would help i guess.

```
std::map<"std::string, std::pair<"std::string", bool>>myMap2
```

`std::pair` can have 2 Key Values Equal(I guess I am Right)...What will be the bool value in each case,will it be TRUE in the first case and FALSE the second time or vice-versa?.

I also heard about `std::tuple` or `boost::tuple` where a single Key can be used to Store Different Values.

I am not very clear about how to iterate through  them...i need help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want [`multimap`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/) instead of `map`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to associate more than one value with a single key, use `std::multimap` (or `std::unordered_multimap`) instead of `std::map`.

In some cases, it can make sense to have a `std::map<key_type, std::vector<mapped_type> >` instead (personally, I frequently find this preferable).

Comment: Instead of using `multimap`, using the `map<??,vector<>>`, is a nice suggestion and in most cases it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store multiple items with the same key, you should use a `multimap` (also applies to `unordered_` variants).

The following should work:

```
std::multimap<std::string,int> mm;
for( int i = 0; i != 10; ++i )
  mm.insert(make_pair("hello world"), i);
```

And your multimap should contain ten entries with key "hello world" and 10 different values.